# Most reliable way to check if user is authenticated or not in Azure AD B2C with SSO

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am planning to use Azure AD B2C as SSO solution for 20 applications we have. 
Question is What is the most reliable way to check if user is authenticated or not regardless of which application user is logged in. Lets say if user is logged in thorough app1 then user goes to anonymous page of app2, at client side i need to make a decision if user is logged in or not.
I was hoping it there is a b2clogin.com endpoint where i can simple make an ajax request and check if user is logged in or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, I suppose there must have be a cookie, so debug with Fiddler, then check if a web page belongs to a domain to any application has right to read it.

Comment: Hi @g.pickardou - sorry but i could not understand your point.

Comment: A user is logged in or not is not a "global" state to be check, a user logged in in a _particular browser in a particular session_ that is a state you are looking for

Comment: Yes i am looking for if a user is logged-in, in a particular browser in a particular session or not.